# Displayed data from firestore is out of order using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, field

This is my first question so I hope the format is OK.

I have a Firestore collection called DeviceEvents.  Each document has three fields always in the same order:

1. 'DeviceID' : integer
2. 'EventCode' : String
3. TimeStamp : Timestamp

I am accessing the data base and printing the contents of my DeviceEvents DB with this code,

```
db = Client("MyDatabase", creds)
docs = db.collection(u'DeviceEvents').stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

But the lines that get printed have the fields in no particular order like this (sorry for the mess),

```
0VvJXxPVQ9gi26Cidk5A => {'DeviceID': 2885359593, 'TIMESTAMP': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 12, 12, 2, 44, 28, 658000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'EventCode': '1'}
4Moup5WQqRVsfvjQDlgl => {'EventCode': '1', 'DeviceID': 2885359593, 'TIMESTAMP': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 12, 12, 2, 44, 3, 260000, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
Y8BwdwTlVy65NpzOTLYV => {'TIMESTAMP': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 12, 22, 18, 39, 50, 221000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'DeviceID': 2885451321, 'EventCode': '1'}
Z4ekuzD6gsUpVXrHdmnC => {'TIMESTAMP': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 12, 20, 17, 29, 54, 819000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'DeviceID': 2885451321, 'EventCode': '1'}
vWdJQr6gWfrtlpfXWklD => {'EventCode': '1', 'TIMESTAMP': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 12, 10, 20, 21, 6, 941000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'DeviceID': 2885359593}
```

If I run the code 10 times the order of the fields will be different every time.  Does anyone know what may be going on?

Comment: What version of python are you using ? I would recomend to follow the official documentation regarding [Retrieving Data Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#python)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. The solution is to format the print command in the order I want. I still don't understand why the fields were randomly out of order before but this bit of print code works.

for doc in docs:
print(u'{} => DeviceID:{}, EventCode: {}, TimeStamp: {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()["DeviceID"], doc.to_dict()["EventCode"], doc.to_dict()["TIMESTAMP"]))